# Creating a bar-chart for top viewed data in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I created an angular project that takes some data(as issue) dynamically and stored as card in a component(issues component). If I click on a particular card, it navigates to issue-details component where entire details of an issue should be shown. Now, I have to create a chart that should display top viewed issues. How can I do this? I am a beginner to Angular.

Any help can be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**issues.component.html:**

```
<h3 *ngIf="default" class="mt-5" style="text-align: center">There is nothing to show. Please raise issue by clicking "Add New" button.</h3>

<app-update (upevent)="upd8=$event" *ngIf="upd8" [ID]="uid"></app-update>

<div  *ngIf="!upd8">
  <div class="card-group">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header bg-white">
        <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="customtoggle()">Customise</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" *ngIf="customClicked">
        <form  #customForm="ngForm">
          <h6 class="card-title align-right">Customise View</h6>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="item1" name="customitem" [(ngModel)]="isCD">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="item1">Created Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="item2" name="customitem"  [(ngModel)]="isDes">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="item2">Description</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="item3" name="customitem"  [(ngModel)]="isSeverity">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="item3">Severity</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="item4" name="customitem"  [(ngModel)]="isStatus">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="item4">Status</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="item5" name="customitem"  [(ngModel)]="isRD">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="item5">Resolved Date</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card text-right">
      <div class="card-header bg-white"> 
        <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="filtertoggle()">Filter</button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" *ngIf="filterClicked">
        <form  #filterForm="ngForm">
          <h6 class="card-title align-right">Severity Filter</h6>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="sevfilter1" name="sevfilter" value="Minor" [(ngModel)]="sevfilter">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="sevfilter1">Minor</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="sevfilter2" name="sevfilter" value="Major" [(ngModel)]="sevfilter">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="sevfilter2">Major</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="sevfilter3" name="sevfilter" value="Critical" [(ngModel)]="sevfilter">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="sevfilter3">Critical</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h6 class="card-title align-right">Status Filter</h6>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="stafilter1" name="stafilter" value="Open" [(ngModel)]="stafilter">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="stafilter1">Open</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="stafilter2" name="stafilter" value="In Progress" [(ngModel)]="stafilter">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="stafilter2">In Progress</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="stafilter3" name="stafilter" value="Resolved"  [(ngModel)]="stafilter">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="stafilter3">Resolved</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let issue of issues" class="mt-1">
    <div *ngIf="issue.Id != 0">
      <div  class="card"  *ngIf="(issue.Severity == sevfilter  || sevfilter == 'none') && (issue.Status == stafilter || stafilter == 'none')">

      <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #563D7C">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <strong class="nav-link text-white">Issue ID: {{issue.Id}}</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" (click)="update(issue)" class="nav-link btn text-white btn-primary float-right">Update</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" (click)="delete(issue.Id)" class="nav-link btn btn-danger float-right">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" style="background-color: #E1D3F7">
        <ul class="list-group">
         **<a [routerLink]="['/issuesdetail',issue.CreatedDate,issue.Description,issue.Severity,issue.Status,issue.ResolvedDate]" routerLinkActive="active">** 
`This is the line where it routes to issue-detail component and displays particular issue`
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="isCD"><strong>Created Date: </strong>{{issue.CreatedDate}}</li>
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="isDes"><strong>Description: </strong>{{issue.Description}}</li>
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="isSeverity"><strong>Severity: </strong>{{issue.Severity}}</li>
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="isStatus"><strong>Status: </strong>{{issue.Status}}</li>
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf='issue.Status == "Resolved" && isRD'><strong>Resolved Date: </strong>{{issue.ResolvedDate}}</li>
        </a>  </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**issues.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocaljsonService } from '../localjson.service';
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from 'node_modules/@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-issues',
  templateUrl: './issues.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./issues.component.css']
})
export class IssuesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _localjsonService: LocaljsonService, private _router: Router){


      }
   
  issues: any;
  default: boolean;
  upd8 = false;
  uid: any;
  customClicked = false;
  filterClicked = false;

  isCD = true;
  isDes = true;
  isSeverity = true;
  isStatus = true;
  isRD = true;

  stafilter = 'none';
  sevfilter = 'none';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.issues = this._localjsonService.getJSON();
    if (this.issues.length < 2) {
      this.default = true;
    } else {
      this.default = false;
    }
    
    console.log(this.calls);

  }
  customtoggle() {
    this.customClicked = !this.customClicked;
  }

  filtertoggle() {
    this.filterClicked = !this.filterClicked;
  }

  update(id: any) {
    this.upd8 = true;
    this.uid = id;
  }

  delete(id: any) {
    for (let i = 1; i < this.issues.length; i++) {
      if ( this.issues[i].Id === id ) {
        this.issues.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    this._localjsonService.setJSON(this.issues);
    if (this.issues.length < 2) {
      // this._router.navigate(['/issues']);
      this.default = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**issue-detail.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
import { LocaljsonService } from '../localjson.service';
import { AddnewComponent } from '../addnew/addnew.component';
import { count } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-issue-detail',
  templateUrl: './issue-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./issue-detail.component.css']
})
export class IssueDetailComponent implements OnInit {

 description!:any;
 createdDate!:string;
 resolvedDate!:string;
 severity!:string;
 status!:string;
  

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, 
    private _localjsonService:LocaljsonService) {
     
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  this.route.paramMap.forEach((params: Params) => {
  console.log(params);

  this.createdDate=params.get("CreatedDate");
  this.description=params.get("Description");
  console.log(this.description);
  this.severity=params.get("Severity");
  this.status=params.get("Status");
  this.resolvedDate=params.get("ResolvedDate");
});

}

goBack(description:string): void {
// Query Parameter Approach    
this.router.navigate(['/issues'], {queryParams: {viewedid: this.description}});
      }
 }
```

**issue-detail.component.html:**

```
<div>
    <h2>Issue Details</h2>
    <div class="card mx-auto" >
    <div class="des">
   
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Created Date: </strong>{{createdDate}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Description: </strong>{{description}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Severity: </strong>{{severity}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Status: </strong>{{status}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Resolved Date: </strong>{{resolvedDate}}</li>
          </ul>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button" (click)="goBack(description.value)">Back</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**issue-tracker.component.ts:(this is the root module)**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink='/about'><strong>Issue Tracker</strong></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/about' routerLinkActive='active'>About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='/issues' routerLinkActive='active'>View-Issue-List</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary float-right" role="button" routerLink='/addnew' routerLinkActive='active'>Add New</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div  class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```